# Can not find ROS folder on my directories

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have instaled ROS and i got this output while instaling ii:

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-ecl-math

> (0.61.0-0trusty-20141230-0416-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-ecl-geometry

> (0.61.0-0trusty-20141230-1212-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-ecl-mobile-robot

> (0.60.0-1trusty-20141230-1216-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-ecl-sigslots

> (0.61.0-0trusty-20141230-1208-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-ecl-streams

> (0.61.0-0trusty-20141230-1206-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-forward-command-controller

> (0.9.1-0trusty-20141230-0438-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-effort-controllers

> (0.9.1-0trusty-20141230-0554-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-fake-localization

> (1.11.14-0trusty-20141230-0937-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-gateway-msgs

> (0.7.8-0trusty-20141230-0034-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-navfn

> (1.11.14-0trusty-20150120-2137-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-global-planner

> (1.11.14-0trusty-20150120-2142-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-openslam-gmapping

> (0.1.0-2trusty-20141229-2204-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-gmapping

> (1.3.5-0trusty-20141230-0937-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-hector-uav-msgs

> (0.3.3-0trusty-20141230-0521-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-hector-quadrotor-controller

> (0.3.3-0trusty-20141230-0524-+0000)
> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-hector-sensors-description

> (0.3.2-0trusty-20150114-1920-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-hector-quadrotor-description

> (0.3.3-0trusty-20150114-2126-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-hector-quadrotor-model

> (0.3.3-0trusty-20141230-0524-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-joy

> (1.10.0-0trusty-20150110-2152-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-hector-quadrotor-teleop

> (0.3.3-0trusty-20150111-0521-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-hector-quadrotor

> (0.3.3-0trusty-20150114-2326-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-joint-limits-interface

> (0.9.1-0trusty-20141230-0500-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-joint-state-controller

> (0.9.1-0trusty-20141230-0445-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-kobuki-dock-drive

> (0.6.0-0trusty-20141230-1216-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-kobuki-msgs

> (0.6.1-0trusty-20141230-0035-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-yocs-cmd-vel-mux

> (0.6.3-0trusty-20141230-0533-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-kobuki-auto-docking

> (0.6.5-0trusty-20141230-1219-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-kobuki-bumper2pc

> (0.6.5-0trusty-20141230-0437-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-kobuki-driver

> (0.6.0-0trusty-20141230-1218-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-kobuki-ftdi

> (0.6.0-0trusty-20141230-0103-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-yocs-velocity-smoother

> (0.6.3-0trusty-20141230-1209-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-kobuki-keyop

> (0.6.5-0trusty-20141230-1213-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-yocs-controllers

> (0.6.3-0trusty-20141230-0433-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-kobuki-random-walker

> (0.6.5-0trusty-20141230-1208-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-kobuki-rapps

> (0.6.5-0trusty-20141230-1222-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-kobuki-safety-controller

> (0.6.5-0trusty-20141230-1208-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-kobuki-node

> (0.6.5-0trusty-20150110-0807-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-uuid-msgs

> (1.0.4-0trusty-20141230-0052-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-service-pair-msgs

> (0.7.8-0trusty-20141230-0434-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-std-msgs

> (0.7.8-0trusty-20141230-0436-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-app-manager-msgs

> (0.7.8-0trusty-20141230-0439-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-python-utils

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1220-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-console

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1201-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-rocon-ebnf

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1206-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-rocon-uri

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1236-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-app-utilities

> (0.7.6-0trusty-20150112-1239-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-rocon-apps

> (0.7.6-0trusty-20150112-1157-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-unique-id

> (1.0.4-0trusty-20141230-0450-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-python-comms

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1212-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-gateway-utils

> (0.7.6-0trusty-20150112-1254-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-python-redis

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1215-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-hub-client

> (0.7.6-0trusty-20150112-1350-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-python-wifi

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1235-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-zeroconf-msgs

> (0.2.1-0trusty-20141230-0053-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-zeroconf-avahi

> (0.2.3-1trusty-20141230-0451-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-gateway

> (0.7.6-0trusty-20150112-1352-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-semantic-version

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1229-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-bubble-icons

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1158-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-rocon-icons
> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1209-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-interaction-msgs

> (0.7.8-0trusty-20141230-0439-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-interactions

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1243-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-master-info

> (0.1.13-0trusty-20150112-1225-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-std-capabilities

> (0.1.0-0trusty-20141229-2149-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-kobuki-description

> (0.6.5-0trusty-20150114-1927-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-kobuki-gazebo-plugins

> (0.4.1-0trusty-20150110-2245-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-smart-battery-msgs

> (0.1.0-0trusty-20141230-0052-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-laptop-battery-monitor

> (0.1.2-0trusty-20150106-0523-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-map-server

> (1.11.14-0trusty-20141230-0942-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-move-base-msgs

> (1.11.14-0trusty-20141230-0421-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rotate-recovery

> (1.11.14-0trusty-20150120-2147-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-move-base

> (1.11.14-0trusty-20150120-2152-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-move-slow-and-clear

> (1.11.14-0trusty-20150120-2137-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-robot-pose-ekf

> (1.11.14-0trusty-20141230-0855-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-navigation

> (1.11.14-0trusty-20150120-2157-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-openni-camera

> (1.9.2-1trusty-20141230-0531-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-rgbd-launch

> (2.1.0-0trusty-20141231-0002-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-openni-launch

> (1.9.5-0trusty-20141231-0013-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-transmission-interface

> (0.9.1-0trusty-20141230-0443-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-ros-control

> (0.9.1-0trusty-20141230-0555-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rospy-message-converter

> (0.3.0-2trusty-20141230-0501-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-stdr-msgs

> (0.2.0-0trusty-20141230-0040-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-stdr-parser

> (0.2.0-0trusty-20141230-0842-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-stdr-robot

> (0.2.0-0trusty-20141230-0908-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-stdr-server

> (0.2.0-0trusty-20141230-0946-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-stdr-gui

> (0.2.0-0trusty-20141230-0950-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-stdr-resources

> (0.2.0-0trusty-20141229-2110-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-turtlebot-capabilities

> (2.3.5-0trusty-20150112-1412-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-turtlebot-description

> (2.3.5-0trusty-20150114-1930-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-yocs-math-toolkit

> (0.6.3-0trusty-20141230-1011-+0000)

> ... A instalar ros-indigo-yocs-msgs

> (0.6.2-0trusty-20141230-0038-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-yocs-virtual-sensor

> (0.6.3-0trusty-20141230-1023-+0000)

> ... Processing triggers for ureadahead

> (0.100.0-16) ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-hub

> (0.7.6-0trusty-20150112-1355-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-rocon-app-manager

> (0.7.6-0trusty-20150112-1358-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-kobuki-capabilities

> (0.6.5-0trusty-20150112-1406-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-turtlebot-bringup

> (2.3.5-0trusty-20150114-2143-+0000)

> ... A instalar

> ros-indigo-turtlebot-navigation
> (2.3.2-0trusty-20150121-0646-+0000)
> ... A instalar
> ros-indigo-turtlebot-gazebo
> (2.2.0-0trusty-20150121-0956-+0000)
> ... A instalar
> ros-indigo-turtlebot-stage
> (2.2.0-0trusty-20150126-2204-+0000)
> ... A instalar
> ros-indigo-turtlebot-stdr

> (2.2.0-0trusty-20150121-0216-+0000)
> ... A instalar
> ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator
> (2.2.0-0trusty-20150126-2211-+0000)
> ... Processing triggers for libc-bin
> (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ... ERROR: default
> sources list file already exists:
> /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
> Please delete if you wish to
> re-initialize

Still i can not find my ROS directory. I have tried to do :

➢ cd ~/ros
➢ git pull
➢ catkin_make

but it says that there is not any ROS directory. This means ROS is not correctly instaled on my computer?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203974/can-not-find-ros-folder-on-my-directories/) by [Luis_Neves_555](https://answers.ros.org/users/21744/luis_neves_555/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installation returned without an error ROS is probably installed. ~/ros is a common place in your home directory to put a workspace where you will install your sources.

The most common reason for this sort of error is that you did not follow all the previous steps in the instructions. It looks like you're following a tutorial. If you'd like more help, please link to the tutorial and provide enough information to reproduce the issue.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0